How to add a user to a ticket using UserSelectMenuBuilder
I managed to create a UserSelectMenuBuilder but I don't know how to make it so that when an interaction occurs (so a user is selected) I can make the channel visible to him and make him write
Can someone help me?
Screen:
UserSelector Image
CODE:
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId === 'adduser') {
        if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(staffrole)) return await interaction.reply({ content: `❗ Non hai i permessi necessari`, ephemeral: true })
        
            
    const channel = interaction.channel;        

    const userMenuEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Aggiungi un Utente al ticket')       
        .setDescription(`Usa il menù qua sotto per aggiungere un utente al ticket ${channel}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('Blue')
        .setFooter({ text: 'PixelTime Tickets'});

    const addMemberMenu = new UserSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('usermenu')
        .setPlaceholder("Seleziona l'utente da aggiungere al ticket")
        .setMinValues(1)
        .setMaxValues(1)

    const userMenu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(addMemberMenu)
    interaction.reply({embeds: [userMenuEmbed], components: [userMenu], ephemeral: true}).catch(error => {return});
    };
});



client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId === 'adduser') {
        if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(staffrole)) return await interaction.reply({ content: '❗ Non hai i permessi necessari', ephemeral: true });

        //Add permissions in the channel where the interaction occurs
 

    };
});

I've already searched online but haven't found anything.
I need to be able to add a user to the channel and have them write
